# Using matplotlib in Python 3 CGI

Tags: python, apache, matplotlib, cgi

I've been trying to run matplotlib on CGI scripts with little success. I'm using Python3.5.

Most of the references I found online show functionality for Python2.x.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os,sys
import cgi
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()

import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pylab

matplotlib.use('Agg')

plt.figure()
plt.plot([1,2,3])

import io
imgData = io.BytesIO()

pylab.savefig(imgData, format='png')

imgData.seek(0)

print("Content-type: image/png")
print()

print(imgData.read())
```

I am running Apache 2.4.18 on Arch Linux, and I get the following error:

```
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.

Error message:
End of script output before headers: index.py

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
```

My script has all required permissions to execute.

Any help will be appreciated.

UPDATE: I moved `matplotlib.use('Agg')` right beneath `import matplotlib` and now it gets past the server header error. The backend was getting declared earlier, hence the statement above has no effect. However, now I get the error:

```
The image 'http://localhost' cannot be displayed since it contains errors.
```

How can I correctly render images?

Comment: You are referencing `pylab` without importing it.

Comment: Imported Pylab, still getting the same error.

Comment: While you're absolutely correct, that doesn't seem to be the primary problem here since it isn't working even on changing it to 'image/png'.

Comment: Did you run this in a terminal? Instead of using `print` at the end, write the data to a file and then open it in the browser. See if that is okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved my problem.

The following is working for me:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os,sys
import cgi
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()

import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')

os.environ['HOME'] = '/tmp'

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([1,2,3])

print("Content-type: image/png")
print()

plt.savefig(sys.stdout, format='png')
```